# Cannot connect to local SQL Server database from a different computer

Tags: sql-server, tcp, port, remote-server

I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26, - Error Locating Server/Instance Specific) (Microsoft SQL Server)

I am trying to allow remote access to my local SQL Server database when the user is using my application on a different computer. I've been trying different approaches for weeks and nothing seems to work.

Here is a list of things that I have tried to do:

- Changed server property settings to Allow remote connections to the server
- Enable TCP/IP and listed 1433 port number in `IPALL` field
- Created inbound rule for SQL Server program, SQL Browser, and port 1433
- Temporarily disabled Windows firewall

Again, I know there is a lot of information surrounding this issue, but I feel like I've implemented every solution I could find and nothing is working.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #1, the [allow remote connections to this server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option) checkbox in SSMS does not actually allow remote client clients to connect despite the misleading name. Use [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager) (e.g. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc, depending on your SQL version) instead. Right-click on SQL Server Network Configuration-->Protocols-->TCP/IP, select Enable, and restart the SQL Server service.